# Get posts from deleted users SQL function

Tags: php, sql, function

Hello I am quite new in Sql and I am remaking one simple PHP dashboard. I have mysql database and I have problem with this query.

```
public function get_posts($thread_id, $start, $limit)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT a.*, b.username, b.id as user_id FROM ".TBL_POSTS." a, ".TBL_USERS." b 
                WHERE a.thread_id = ".$thread_id." AND a.author_id = b.id 
                ORDER BY a.date_add ASC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$limit;
        return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
```

The situation which can happen is that a.author id is not equal to b.id because user was deleted. I need to improve my sql to show posts of deleted users and show some information that post is by deleted user.

Thank you

Comment: This contains too little information for us to be able to help. What do the tables look like, what have you tried, what is the expected outcome (since it can't select b.username if b is deleted.) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below. It chooses all the rows in table b and finds all the matches in table a or puts NULL in all fields of a if there is no corresponding row in a.

```
SELECT a.*, b.username, b.id as user_id FROM ".TBL_POSTS." a LEFT JOIN ".TBL_USERS." b
            ON a.author_id = b.id
            WHERE a.thread_id = ".$thread_id
```

Comment: Sorry, changed to Left Join. Did not understand what table had missing data.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

You must use [Foreig Keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) and add LEFT join to your query